# Why does '.attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)' work?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the `d3.drag()` to drag text.

Some people use `d3.select("text").attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)` to change the postion of text. I have read the D3 docs, I found that in `selection.attr(name,value)` the value can be a constant or function.

So I wonder, why `selection.attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)` can work?

Answer (score 2):

In the `attr()` method you shared the `value` is just a constant (more precisely a property of an object), which satisfies what the docs say.

For providing some context for this answer, you're probably using it inside a function like this...

```
function dragged(d) {
    selection.attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x);
}
```

... which you can see at the very [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#event_on).

In the above snippet `d` is the datum, nothing new here. Regarding `d3.event.x`, the same API will show you:

> When a drag event listener is invoked, d3.event is set to the current drag event. The event object exposes several fields:
>
> - `x` - the new x-coordinate of the subject;

So, what that code in your question is doing is getting the new x-coordinate (that is, `d3.event.x`), setting its value to `d.x` and returning it to the `attr()` method, all this in a single expression. Have in mind that the assignment is important: if you remove it you'll see the element "jumping" when you try to drag it again.

This pattern is something that people normally do in JavaScript, and it saves you the trouble of getting a value, passing it to a variable and returning it in different lines: you can do it all in just one line. For instance, take a look at this function, the `return` will initialise the `x` variable and return `10` at the same time:

```js
var x;

function foo() {
  return x = 10;
};

console.log(foo())
```

To make this even more clear: `d.x = d3.event.x` is an *expression*, and it will evaluate to a single value. Have a look here:

```js
console.log(foo = "bar")
```

In conclusion, your method is the same of:

```
function dragged(d) {
    d.x = d3.event.x
    selection.attr("cx", d3.event.x);
    //just a constant---------^
}
```

As you can see, `attr()` is receiving just a constant as the second argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am still confused. You mean the expression like "d.x = d3.event.x" is from JavaScript not D3, but you can look at this example.[link](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/22994cc97fefaeede0d861e6815a847e) Could you give me some help again?

Comment: @DechengLi I never said that the expression *is from JavaScript not D3*, whatever that means. Also, have in mind that D3 is a Javascript library. Everything in D3 is Javascript.

Comment: yeah, when I delete the 'd.x = d3.event.x', the element that I want to drag will **"jump"** when I drag it again. I don't think the **d.x** and **attr("x")** are relative. Could you explain why the element **jump**?

Comment: @DechengLi First, welcome to Stack Overflow. The comments section is just for clarification regarding the current answer, please don't ask new questions in the comments section. Also, for your information, this question (regarding the "jump") was already asked/answered here many many times, just do a search. Finally, make sure that you read the entire tour: https://stackoverflow.com/Tour.